# What is Difference between IP address and Port Number in Networking?

Tags: networking, ip, port

What is Difference between IP address and Port Number in Networking?

Comment: I found this helpful: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/15702/port-number

Comment: Please refer my post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54760661/2197108 and for more info please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54760498/2197108

Answer (score 26):

**IP address** is address of the system in the Network.

**Port** is address of the service within the System.

So *IP address + Port* defines address of the particular service on the particular system.

Answer (score 14):

Think about how many application layer protocols exist (**HTTP**, **FTP**, **DNS**, **SSH**, etc). Now think about how many **task**/**process**/**programs** exist within your device trying to communicate over the internet. Would it be possible just one address, the **IP** address, to be able to handle all these different assignments and types of protocols alone? The answer is no.

The **IP** address is a numerical label assigned to each **device** connected to a computer network that uses the Internet Protocol for communication. The **port number** is used so the data is directed to the correct location **within this device**.

The **IP** and the **port number** form the structure IP:port number, `192.168.1.1:8080` for example, and the **port number** can hold **65536** numbers, with the following division:

- **0 to 1023** - Well known port numbers. Only special companies like Apple QuickTime, MSN, SQL Services, Gopher Services and other prominent services have these port numbers.
- **1024 to 49151** - Registered ports; meaning they can be registered to specific protocols by software corporations.
- **49152 to 65535** - Dynamic or private ports; meaning that they can be used by just about anybody.

Comment: Super explanation, specially for port- The port number is used so the data is directed to the correct location within this device.

Comment: very well explained :)

Answer (score 6):

IP address is use to identify a host or a group of hosts in a network
while port number is used to identify a particular service running in a host

Answer (score 4):

Port number is used to identify an application/services which you want to talk to on your system. Some predefined ports like 80 = HTTP server, 23 = Telnet.

You identify a host uniquely (globally) by its IP address. So if I ever wanted to access your laptop via telnet then I'd use the IP address given to you by your ISP and the port 23

Answer (score 3):

A MAC address is a layer-2 address. It is used by some layer-2 protocols, e.g. ethernet and Wi-Fi. There are 48-bit and 64-bit MAC addresses. Some layer-2 protocols use different addressing.

An IP address is the address of the layer-3 IP protocol. Different layer-3 protocols use different addressing, e.g. IPv4, IPX, and IPv6 each have different addressing.

A port number is a layer-4 address used by some layer-4 protocols, e.g. TCP and UDP. Some layer-4 protocols use different addressing, or none at all.

TCP example: [RFC 793, TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)

> Multiplexing:
>
> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
>   communication facilities simultaneously, ***the TCP provides a set of
>   addresses or ports within each host***.  Concatenated with the network
>   and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
>   socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection. That
>   is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections.

You may want to learn more about the network layers.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by layer-2? And what is a layer-1?

Comment: @Honey, the network layers are used to describe the network stack. You have layer-1, the physical layer (cabling, encoding, signalling), layer-2 the data-link layer (ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, PPP, frame relay, ATM, HDLC, etc.), layer-3 is the network layer (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.), layer-4 is the transport layer (TCP, UDP, SCTP, DCCP, etc.). There are different models, but search for `network layer model` or something similar. There are entire book chapters about this, so it is too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

- A socket is like a telephone (i.e. end to end device for communication)
- IP is like your telephone number (i.e. address of your socket)
- Port is like the person you want to talk to (i.e. the service you want to order from that address)

In networking, generally a socket is (IP+Port)

Answer (score 0):

**IP address:**  Ip address is a address of your system, it assign when your system connects to internet.There are two types of ip address available here among first one is dynamic which invokes at your system in online. Second one is static, which assign when your system get in offline.

**port address**  Port address is an Id of server such as your using apache server that get port number default 8080 is id of apache server,If you can change server port number.

Answer (score -1):

IP address is your system domain name or socket address of specific system like 192.168.0.1

but the port number is the number of specific location or folder where to you want to write your file or any file transfer like: 3308

Comment: Since HTTP use port 80 and you said "port number is the number of specific location or folder where to you want to write your file", if 2 applications are using http both have port 80, how will you identify incoming data is for which application as both share same IP and Port?

Comment: @Usama : There can't be 2 applications running on same IP and same Port

Comment: yes 2 application can't run on same ip and same port at a time but if you change port for second application then it will work

Answer (score -1):

The IP address of your computer (host) is the mix of the network ID of the ISP/any other provider (uniquely provided by the ICANN group) and the host name (provided by the Network administrator). The Network ID is unique for all the network and among two networks, we can have same host names but on the same network, the host names can not be the same. So, this is how the host can be identified on the network and data can be transferred. But on the same host multiple applications will be running and once the data reach to the host, we need an identifier to recognize which application data is this TCP Segment/UDP datagram.

The Port number is 16 bits (possibly 65K application can run) and assigned by the Network operating system when the application process creates the sockets. On the Server side, the port numbers are well defined numbers (HTTP- Port #80, SMTP- Port#25). The port number is transport layer addressing (L4) and goes in the header of TCP/UDP.