# multiple client process connect to 1 server process

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm making C socket program that 1 server process communicates to 1 client process of all 4 processes in turn.

More specifically, when the client and the server talk to each other 10 messages(5 messages for each), the other client who's waiting for connecting to the server connects and do the same thing. Each clients must have different ports (8000-8003) when connecting.

I think my program below communicates to only 1 client which matches to the same port with the server(8000).

What should I do with this when there should be just 1 server process and 4 client processes using different ports?

**screentshot from client**
[image]

**screenshot from server**
[image]

**client.c**

```c
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int c_socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    char fromServer[100];
    int str_len;
    int PORT = 8000;


    int count = 0; 

    int status; 
    pid_t wait_pid;

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork failed!\n");
        return 0;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // P-C1
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("fork failed!\n");
            return 0;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            // P-C1-C3
            PORT = 8003;
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            // P-C1
            PORT = 8001;
        }
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        // P
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("fork failed!\n");
            return 0;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            // P-C2
            PORT = 8002;
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            // P
            PORT = 8000;
        }
    }

    printf("pid: %d ppid: %d\n", pid, getppid());

    c_socket_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("Created Client Socket\n");

    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(connect(c_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == 0) {
        printf("Connected Server\n");

        while (1) {
            char toServer[100] = "Hello Server, this is message No. ";
            char* ch = toServer;

            while (*ch != '\0') {
                ch++;
            }

            *ch = ('0' + count);
            ch++;
            char temp[7] = " from ";
            char* temp_ch = temp;
            while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                *ch = *temp_ch;
                temp_ch++;
                ch++;
            }

            int process_id = pid;
            if (process_id >= 10000) {
                char temp[6] = {0,};
                sprintf(temp, "%d", process_id);
                char* temp_ch = temp;
                while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                    *ch = *temp_ch;
                    temp_ch++;
                    ch++;
                }
            } else if (process_id >= 1000) {
                char temp[5] = {0,};
                sprintf(temp, "%d", process_id);
                char* temp_ch = temp;
                while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                    *ch = *temp_ch;
                    temp_ch++;
                    ch++;
                }
            } else if (process_id >= 100) {
                char temp[4] = {0,};
                sprintf(temp, "%d", process_id);
                char* temp_ch = temp;
                while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                    *ch = *temp_ch;
                    temp_ch++;
                    ch++;
                }
            } else if (process_id >= 10) {
                char temp[3] = {0,};
                sprintf(temp, "%d", process_id);
                char* temp_ch = temp;
                while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                    *ch = *temp_ch;
                    temp_ch++;
                    ch++;
                }
            } else {
                char temp[2] = {0,};
                sprintf(temp, "%d", process_id);
                char* temp_ch = temp;
                while(*temp_ch != '\0') {
                    *ch = *temp_ch;
                    temp_ch++;
                    ch++;
                }
            }

            ch++;
            *ch = '\0';

            count++;
            if (count > 5) {
                if (pid > 0)
                wait_pid = wait(&status);
                if (wait_pid != -1)
                    break;
            }

            write(c_socket_fd, toServer, sizeof(toServer));

            read(c_socket_fd, fromServer, sizeof(fromServer));
            printf("From Server: %s\n", fromServer);
        }

        close(c_socket_fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**server.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORT 8000

int main() {
    int s_socket_fd, c_socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_size = sizeof(client_address);

    char toClient[100] = "Hello Client, this is my reply for your message No. ";
    char fromClient[100];

    s_socket_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s_socket_fd == -1) {
        printf("socket create failed!\n");
        close(s_socket_fd);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Server Socket Created!\n");

    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if ((bind(s_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address))) == -1) {
        printf("bind failed!\n");
        close(s_socket_fd);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((listen(s_socket_fd, 10) == -1)) {
        printf("listen failed!\n");
        close(s_socket_fd);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Waiting Client...\n");

    client_address_size = sizeof(client_address);
    c_socket_fd = accept(s_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &client_address_size);
    if (c_socket_fd == -1) {
        printf("accept failed!\n");
        close(c_socket_fd);
        close(s_socket_fd);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Client Connected!\n");

    while(1) {
        read(c_socket_fd, fromClient, sizeof(fromClient));
        printf("From Client message: %s\n", fromClient);

        char* count = strstr(fromClient, " from");
        count--;
        char* temp_ch = toClient;
        while (*temp_ch != '\0') {
            temp_ch++;
        }
        *(temp_ch-1) = *count;

        write(c_socket_fd, toClient, sizeof(toClient));
    }


    close(c_socket_fd);
    close(s_socket_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There must be several millions of C socket and networking tutorials and examples all over the greater Internet.Most decent ones (which is the majority I'd say) would show servers using a *loop* to handle multiple clients, one after the other (for example like `while (1) { c_socket_fd = accept(...); ... }`)

Comment: Also note that a problem with `accept` doesn't mean your passive listening server socket might be in a state of error. It really depends on the error itself.

Comment: If you need to use multiple ports in the server for the clients to connect to, you need multiple sockets, and need to multiplex between them in one way or another. Most tutorials and books about concurrency in network programming should show multiple ways to handle multiple clients using a single server socket. The same technique could be used for multiple server sockets. Or you could just fork the number of needed processes (or create threads instead), and let each process create a single server socket to handle a single connection each.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740609/multiport-listening-socket-linux and https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/312389/Listening-on-multiple-ports-on-a-single-server

Comment: But, do you want `8000-8003` _just_ to have 4 clients connect simultaneously? If so, that's different. Server does `listen(8000,10)`. When client connects to port 8000, it will be given a _different_ (available) port number (e.g. 12345, 12346, ...). When server does `accept`, the connection is established with the random/available port number. If the server has to `listen` on 4 ports `8000-8003`, it needs to do 4 separate bind/listen calls and keep track of them separately. And, up to 10 clients can connect on a given server listen port. So, server has to keep track of 40 conversations.

Comment: Usually, server does `listen` on a _single_ port. Loops on `accept`. After `accept`, server forks a child, giving it the socket fd. Server's child process talks to client, closes socket and end. Server does `waitpid` on the child [or fields `SIGCHLD`]. So, multiport _listening_ is different than just having multiple client conversations going. If you truly want it, you'll need more to keep track of this. If you want _one_ server process, it's even more messy because all calls have to be non-blocking (i.e. you need `select` and timeout the `accept`). Probably, _not_ what you _really_ want