# Is there a way to connect sockets from perl script to a PHP server?

Tags: php, perl, sockets, tcp, xampp

I am new to the concept of web socket connections and this would be of real help to me.
I have XAMPP running on a local machine.
How can i connect via a socket to the APACHE server on this machine ?
I am not getting any leads. Is there a tutorial to set that up ?
Also how do I control what happens when a socket connection is made towards the server side ?

Comment: Your message seems to be too vague. As a first step, try to read  this Q, it could be usefoul for you: [What is the difference between a port and a socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to connect to a web server on localhost and fetch a document from it.  The easiest way to do that is to not worry about interacting with sockets directly and instead use a prepackaged web client library, such as [LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) or [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple).