# Socket and Port

Tags: sockets, ports

I'm studying Java and am following this client and server example, but I'd like to understand the difference between a socket and a port. If a server serves web pages on port 80, then how can thousands of clients connect to that port? What is the difference between a port and a socket?

I know there's a limit on the number of ports, but is there a limitation on the number of sockets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket