# Confused between ports and sockets

Tags: networking, port, ip-address

Ok so when I tried to do research on ip addresses, ports, and sockets, this is what I got out of it:

IP Addresses are used to map to different devices over a network.

Port numbers are used to get to the specific application on the hosts.

Sockets are a combination of the two..

What I don't understand is that if ports connect you to a specific application, you should only have 1 port number per application right? But for example port 80 is used for HTTP, so if an application is using that port it's listening to HTTP requests right? So what happens if more than one person tries to access it? Sockets and ports have me confused a lot..

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket?rq=1

Comment: it`s one listenersocket (defined port) but the connection socket on you side can change (undefined port, just random). 
Only to mention it: one app may of course USE more ports.. think of FTP: Port 21 is the command port whereas 20 is the dataport

Comment: @InnotKauker, although it is highly upvoted, that answer is a bit inaccurate. It also uses unnecessarily complicated language to explain something very simple. I'm just writing up a more "down-to-earth" answer, on this thread...

Answer (score 8):

A socket is an abstraction used in software to make it easier for programmers to send and receive data through networks. They are an interface, which you use in application-level code, to access the underlying network protocol implementations provided by your OS and language runtime.

The TCP protocol, IP protocol, and other popular network protocols do not, *in of themselves*, have any concept of "sockets". "Sockets" are a concept which *implementers* of TCP/IP came up with.

So what is the concept of a "socket"? Basically, an object which you can write data to, and read data from. "Opening" a socket means creating one of those objects in your program's memory. You can also "close" a socket, which means freeing any system resources which that object uses behind the scenes.

Some kinds of sockets can be "bound" to local and remote addresses, which you can think of as setting some data fields, or properties, on the socket object. The value of those fields affect what happens when you read from or write to the socket.

In Unix, there are various kinds of sockets. If you "open" a **TCP socket**, "bind" it to local and remote addresses (and ports), and write some data into it, your libraries/OS will package that data up into a TCP segment and send it out through whichever network interface matches the local address which you "bound" the socket to. If you "open" an **IP socket**, and write some data to it, that data will be packaged up into a IP packet (without any added TCP headers) and sent out. If you open a "raw", **link-level socket**, and write to it, the data will be sent out as the payload of a link-level frame, minus IP *and* TCP headers. There are also **"Unix domain sockets"**. If you open one of those and write to it, the data will be passed directly through system memory to another process on the same machine.

So although they are often used in non-OO languages like C, sockets are a perfect example of what OO languages call "polymorphism". If you ever have trouble explaining what "polymorphism" is to someone, just teach them about network sockets.

"Ports" are a completely different concept. The idea of "ports" is *built in* to TCP and other transport protocols.

Others may give more high-falutin', and perhaps more technically accurate, definitions of a "port". Here is one which is totally down to earth:

A "port" is a **number** which appears in the TCP headers on a TCP segment. (Or the UDP headers on a UDP segment.)

Just a number. Nothing more, nothing less.

If you are using a "socket"-based interface to do network programming, the significance of that number is that each of your TCP or UDP sockets has a "local port" property, and a "remote port" property. As I said before, setting those properties is called "binding".

If your socket's "local port" property is "bound" to 80, then all the TCP segments you send out will have "80" in the "sender port" header. Then, when others respond to your messages, they will put "80" in their "destination port" headers.

More than that, if your socket is "bound" to local port 80, then when data arrives from elsewhere, addressed to your port 80, the OS will pass it to *your application process* and not any other. Then, when you try to read from the socket, that data will be returned.

Obviously, the OS needs to know what port each of your sockets is bound to. So when "binding", system calls must be made. If your program is not running with sufficient privileges, the OS may refuse to let you bind to a certain port. Then, depending on the language you are using, your networking library will throw an exception, or return an error code.

Sometimes the OS may refuse to let you bind to a certain port, not because you don't have the right privileges, but because *another* process has already bound to it. *However*, and this is what some of the other answers get wrong, if certain flags are set when opening a socket, your OS may allow *more than one* socket to be bound to the same local address and port.

You still don't know what "listening" and "connected" sockets are. But once you understand the above, that will just be a small jump.

**The above explains the difference between what we today call a "socket" and what we call a "port". What may still not be clear is: why do we need to make that distinction?**

You have really got me thinking here (thank you)! Could we call the software abstraction which is called a "socket" a "port" instead, so that instead of calling `socket_recv` you would call `port_recv`?

If you are only interested in TCP and UDP, *maybe* that would work. Remember, the "socket" abstraction is not only for TCP and UDP. It is also for other network protocols, as well as for inter-process communication on the same machine.

Then again, a TCP socket does not only map to a port. A "connected" TCP socket maps to a local IP address, local port, remote address, *and* remote port. It *also* has other associated data, including various flags, send and receive buffers, sequence numbers for the incoming/outgoing data streams, and various other variables used for congestion control (rate limiting), etc. That data does *not* belong just to a local port.

There can be thousands of TCP connections going simultaneously through the same "port". Each of those connections has its own associated data, and the software object which encapsulates that per-connection data is a "TCP socket".

Even if you only use TCP/UDP, and even if you only have a single process using any given local port at one time, and even if you only have a single connection going through each local port at one time, I think the "socket" abstraction *still* makes sense. If we just called sockets "ports", there would be more meanings conflated in that one word. Reusing the same word for too many meanings hinders communication.

"Ports" are transport-protocol level identifiers for an application process. "Sockets" are the objects used in software to send/receive messages which are addressed from/to those identifiers.

Differentiating between "my address" and "the thing which sends letters addressed as coming from me" is a useful distinction to make. "My address" is just a label. A label is not something active, which does things like sending data. It is logical to give "the thing which is used to send data" its own name, different from the name which denotes "the sender address which the data is labelled with".

Comment: So why can't you just "write data" to a port number? What's the point of having a socket? I don't understand the difference between them, they both identify an application process...

Comment: Very interesting conceptual question! I have added more information which may make things clearer to you.

Comment: Oh okay so if an application process has more than one incoming connection, even though the same port is being used because its one application, you need sockets to differentiate between the different connections right?

Comment: @user3843164, if you are using TCP, yes, that is correct. Besides one socket for each TCP connection *through the same port*, you will also have one "listening" socket which is used to accept new connections.

Answer (score 0):

When application (say web server like Apache or Nginx) is listening on say port 80, it creates so called listening socket.

When some client comes, this listening socket gets update (which can be noticed via `select` or `poll` API), and our application creates communication socket. This socket is uniquely identified by tuple `(src_addr, src_port, dst_addr, dst_port)` - it is very much possible that many clients will have exact same (dst_addr, dst_port) combination.

Then our web server can talk over that communication socket to deliver say web page and eventually close this socket. When many clients come in parallel, web server can either create thread/process per client (Apache model), or service all sockets one by one (Nginx model).

Note that in this situation only one listening socket per port can exist - multiple application cannot bind to the same port like 80. But, it is perfectly ok to have many communication sockets (some people report successfully serving more than a million simultaneous requests).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you accept a connection on a socket in *listening state* (e.g. on port 80), you will get a *new* socket in *established state* that represents a connection.

On the client side, each time a new connection (new socket that is being connected) is being made with that address and port, the operating system will assign a random port on your side.

For example if you connect two times:

```
your-host:22482 <---> remote-host:80
your-host:23366 <---> remote-host:80
```