# Difference between lsof -i :<port> & socket statistics ss -lp | grep <port>?

Tags: linux, sockets, pid, lsof, ss

I'm using AWS linux / RHEL and I am trying to identify & remove zombie PIDs that are hogging ports to ensure clean start/stopping of application services.

man lsof -i : will give me the "listing of files any of whose Internet address
matches the address specified in i." so in this case my current hosts's .

```
[sas@hostname init.d]$ sudo lsof -i:8983
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4670 solr  154u  IPv6  25276      0t0  TCP *:8983 (LISTEN)
```

man ss -lp will give me the "socket statistics" for all listening ports and their associated PID.

```
[sas@hostname init.d]$ sudo ss -lp 2>/dev/null | grep 8983
tcp   LISTEN 0      50                                                   *:8983                           *:*     users:(("java",pid=4670,fd=154))
```

I would expect the two to match all the time, so what is going on here?

```
[sas@hostname init.d]$ sudo ss -lp 2>/dev/null | grep 8080
[sas@hostname init.d]$
[sas@hostname init.d]$ sudo lsof -i:8080 | grep -v CLOSE_WAIT
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    17493  sas  469u  IPv6  71422      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
java    17493  sas  689u  IPv6 282980      0t0  TCP localhost:webcache->localhost:60754 (ESTABLISHED)
java    26885  sas 1160u  IPv6 286908      0t0  TCP localhost:60754->localhost:webcache (ESTABLISHED)

## Showing that ss does grab this webcache thing:
[sas@hostname init.d]$ sudo ss -lp 2>/dev/null | grep web
tcp   LISTEN 0      100                                                  *:webcache                       *:*     users:(("java",pid=17493,fd=469))
```

Is there something ss is missing? Am I looking for the wrong thing? Why does lsof catch the port and ss not catch a listening port?

Comment: I have read some notes on the difference between ports & sockets, but these are not helping me understand what is going on here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356976/confused-between-ports-and-sockets
& 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356976/confused-between-ports-and-sockets

Comment: Not programming or development, but: **`ss` by default outputs the _names_ (when known)** of 'services' (also hosts) thus it outputs 'webcache' instead of '8080' and there is no '8080' in the data you ask `grep` to match; `ss` has not itself done ANY matching. (The same was/is true of `netstat`, the older program for this function.) You can use flag `-n` to output the numbers, making them available for matching _and_ display. `lsof` also _displays_ the names but it has done the matching internally using the number(s); it can similarly be given `-n` to display the numbers instead.

Comment: Also note `ss -l` only shows sockets in LISTEN state, so you will never find ESTABLISHED connections that way, if that is what you want. For that simply _remove_ flag `-l`. For that matter even a CLOSE_WAIT socket, which you currently ignore, will prevent reuse of the port (or more exactly the address and port combination) by a different process.

Comment: Ah! Thank you @dave_thompson_085!  Now this makes more sense - ss was displaying the name it found and not the "numeric" of the port.

If you add this as an answer - I will mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are grepping the `ss` output on the port. By default `ss` (and most other tools) output service names instead of port numbers. Apparently port 8080 is mapped to the webcache service name.

Use `ss --numeric` to output port numbers.