# how does my computer handle multiple socket connections?

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

So I've written some python code that starts up two or three separate processes that each listen on different ports of the same socket, and then send the received data on to three different ports of local host.

I've noticed a slowdown when running more and more of these processes concurrently, and after testing to make sure the processes were running concurrently I can't come up with an explanation other than they are taking turns using the socket instead of all at the same time.

I couldn't find an explanation through google so can someone explain to me how exactly my computer handles connecting to multiple sockets and ports? Does it take turns connecting to each or can it connect to all of them simultaneously and send data and receive data simultaneously as well? Thanks.

Comment: Are you starting up separate processes? Or separate threads?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? You will get a better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful:

http://www.nyu.edu/classes/jcf/g22.2262-001_sp10/slides/session10/JavaSockets.pdf

[What is the difference between a port and a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket)

Since everything is sent via packets, it must take turns at some level.

Comment: ran some tests and can confirm this is what was happening.