# Performance difference between unix socket and host:port

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I am running a nginx server to serve by PHP website in Alpine Linux. I see that nginx can connect to php-fpm process via either unix socket or host:port. Are there any practical and/or theoretical performance difference between these 2 methods?

Comment: Typically a file system based socket is faster, since it cuts out the overhead required for the networking layer. Also it reduces the potential security vulnerabilities, since you do not have to open a port at all, which would have to be secured again afterwards.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/195328/unix-socket-vs-tcp-ip-hostport

Comment: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-sysctl-tweaking/#using-tcpip-for-fpm

Comment: Also worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket - think this might be most definitive answer. Perhaps close as dupe if you feel it answers your question.