# What exactly is a message channel?

Tags: message-channel

I've done my research. Basically, a message channel is the way an api can send a message to another api. But what, literally, is a message channel? Is it like a port? Or do you just implement it in your code?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a port and a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket).

Comment: Oh wow. I totally forgot about sockets. I'll look into this.