# Difference between UDP socket and TCP socket number of connections

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

Since UDP sockets are identified by (dst IP, dst Port), is it correct to assume that a client can only send packets through one UDP socket to a particular application process ( assuming the application process uses one port ) running on the server side ? Whereas in TCP, because TCP sockets can be identified by (src IP , src port , dst IP , dst port ), there can be multiple TCP connections to the same dst port on the server side, with each TCP socket on the client side using a different source port. Hope this question doesnt sound weird.

Comment: The number of connections would certainly be different because UDP does not use connections, and it it will always have no connections, but TCP only uses connections. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152863/3745413).

Comment: I think that is basically correct. I'm not sure if there is a practical difference though.