# What will happen if a server machine listens on more 65536 ports?

Tags: sockets, tcp, port, apache-storm

In the case of Storm, it says "Each worker uses a single port for receiving messages, and this setting defines which ports are open for use.", which means I can set the slot number to a number greater than 65536 so that a server machine could open more than 65536 processes and each of them listens on a unique port?

It's not how many tcp connections at a time, I know that tcp connections can be more than 65536.

So what will happen a server machine opens more than 65536 processes and listens on more that 65536 ports?

Comment: There are only 65536 ports. You can't add more than what actually exist just by using a bigger number. You have 8 fingers and 2 thumbs on your hands, and you can't just say *now I have 16 fingers and 4 thumbs* and have it change the type of gloves you need. And **stop writing everything in bold**. It's for **emphasis**, and you don't need **emphasis** on every question in your post. Stop editing it back in.

Comment: See [What is the difference between a port and a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152457/62576). Ignore the accepted answer; it's too long and will confuse the issue. Read the other answers to the question.

Comment: @Ken, I'm justing questioning about the corner case of Storm worker configuration. By the way, if my server wanna serves as http, ftp... (more than 65536 services), how do you solve this problem?

Comment: @asapdiablo You can't solve it. You can't have it. You are asking questions about impossible things. NB there are only ***65535*** ports, as zero is reserved.

Comment: There is no corner case. There are only 66535 ports. Period. No corners, no curves, no nothing other than a hard limit on the ports that are available. And as far as *if my server wanna serves as http...*, that has nothing to do with the number of ports. See the post I linked above.

Comment: @KenWhite There are only 65,535 port numbers but there are more than 65,535 distinct ports available. For example, 1.2.3.4:1234 is a different port from 1.2.3.5:1234. The pair of the destination IP address and the port number forms the listening port and when you connect to a port, you must choose both of these parameters to select what listening socket you wind up connected to.

Comment: @David: That's not a port. A port is a number between 1 and 65535, such as the port 80 used by HTTP. Certainly 1.2.3.4 is different than 1.2.3.5 - they go to different IP addresses. You're confusing terminology. See the link I provided above. No one is discussing *connections* and IP addresses. The question specifically asked about *listening on more than 65535 ports*, and that's not possible. Connections are not ports. You can have multiple connections on a single port (again, referencing HTTP on port 80).

Comment: @KenWhite Those are port numbers, not ports. Port 80 on machine A is a different port from port 80 on machine B and connections to one will never be mistaken for connections to the other. If you can easily distinguish the destinations of two connections, they cannot be to the same port. A port is a logical destination for a connection. "*In computer networking, a port is an endpoint of communication. ... At the software level, within an operating system, a port is a logical construct that identifies a specific process or a type of network service.*"

Comment: @David: Yep. You're right. Machine A's port 80 will never be confused with Machine B's port, because they're on different machines. I think we're talking apples and oranges here, and you've gone somewhere that isn't what the question asked about in the first place (and probably confused the poster more than they were when the question was asked).

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, I think the poster is confused precisely because he doesn't understand that while there are only 65,536 port *numbers* there are more than 65,536 ports.

Comment: The poster is confused because he is asking a meaningless question. The question is of the form 'what shape is a square circle'. He is asking what happens when a limit that cannot be exceeded is exceeded.

Comment: @user207421 This question originates from an interview. When I said the storm worker process uses a single port, and the interviewer immediately raised the question "What if ports are not enough?".  Now I get it, this question is a trap.

Comment: 65535 unique ports not 65536 as port 0 represents a random available port

Answer (score 2):

When a process listens on a TCP port, it doesn't just listen on a port *number*. It listens on a combination of port number and IP address. Wildcard IP addresses can be used to indicate listening on all IP addresses.

For local connections, you can use IP addresses like 127.0.0.2 or 127.1.0.1 in combination with various port numbers to exceed 65,536 local ports. You can have more than 65,536 ports in this way and it works fine. However, IP addresses inside 127.0.0.0/8 cannot be reached from other machines, so it's local only.

To have a port that can accept inbound connections over a network, you must bind it to a combination of an IP address that is reachable over that network with a TCP port number. So a machine with only one network address can only have 65,535 distinct ports that incoming TCP connections can be made to. But you can exceed this by assigning additional network IP addresses to the machine, assuming the software you are using allows you to specify the IP address to bind to. (If not, you can easily hack it to allow that.)